# _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>') in API call flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my model class and factory method,

```
class City {
  String? city;

  City({
    this.city,
  });

  factory City.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return City(
      city: parsedJson["cities"],
    );
  }
}
```

here is the API call,
Exception occurs in the for loop.
Exception was type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

```
Future<CityListState> getCityList() async {
    List<City> cityList = [];
    CityListState cityListState = const CityListSuccessfullyLoaded();
    ApiConnectionRepository(
      success: (title, message, data) {
        printLogs('cityy $data');
        final cities = (data["cities"] ?? []) as List;

         for(var element in cities ){
           print(element);
          cityList.add(City.fromJson(element));
         }

        cityListState = CityListSuccessfullyLoaded(city: cityList);
      },
      failed: (title, message, data) {
        cityListState = CityListLoadedFailed(title: title, message: message);
       
      },
    ).fetchProcessedData(ApiConstants.getCityList, {});

    return cityListState;
  }
```

Comment: Can you include your response data?

Comment: Can you print `cities` and show the result?

Comment: I did its a list

Comment: jsonDecode("your string");

Comment: it's already decoded